# Mark comment as answer

Tags: support, etiquette, voting, accepted-answer

I'm new to this style of forum software. How do I mark a question thread in this forum as answered (presumably beneficial for potential future viewers of the question) when the answer was given in a comment? Also, what tag should this post have used, since I can't post without one?

Comment: Hello and welcome. Take the [Tour](https://blender.stackexchange.com/tour) to understand how this works

Comment: Questions *about* the site should always go to meta (which is where the question is now). Please read through the [tour] and also read the [What is "meta"](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta) FAQ page for some more information.

Comment: You can [upvote the answer that helped you](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote). If you feel it completely solved your issue consider [marking it as accepted](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer).

Answer (score 10):

If an answer has been posted in the comment sections but the person didn't post it as an answer, you can go ahead and post it as an answer and mark it as answered afterwards.

Common "courtesy" is to wait a little bit (I'd say at least one day, but that is subjective)  before doing so because some people prefer taking their time before posting a fully-fledged answer. You can ping an user by using @ then their username to directly ask them what they think about it.

Notes :

Comments are often not posted as answers even if they solve your problem because they would objectively make bad answers : Answers should be fully fledged, include details, diagrams, documentation, references, which are impossible to put in a comment. If you're going to post a comment as an answer, try to include as much detail as possible.

If your problem has been answered by a simple comment, there is a chance that either :

- It is a very simple problem that has already been asked and answered many times, and the person couldn't be bothered to or couldn't find a duplicate of your problem
- It is very specific, and couldn't possibly help another user
- It may thread on the site guidelines for questions and could be closed because of it

Answer (score -1):

Leftside Under the up and down arrows for the score is a checkmark ✔️ click it. It turns green.

Answer (score -2):

You don't.

If you'd like to, you can repeat the answer given in comments in an answer you make yourself, and then mark that as the answer.  Anybody that helps in comments and not answers probably doesn't care about SE points (which are worthless anyways) so you should feel absolutely no shame in collecting the points they would otherwise accrue.

If your goal with marking an answer as correct is to say "Thanks," actually saying that is worth more than any points, but speaking for myself, it's hardly necessary, and some other people on SE might frown upon that.

If your goal with marking an answer as correct is to improve Blender SE, there are usually more important things to do than marking the correct answer.  Things get answered in comments for reasons.  If that reason is that the question is well dealt with elsewhere, it's better to get the question closed (with a redirect) than to get an answer marked.  If that reason is that the comments were part of an exchange seeking more information, it's more important that that information get added to the question than that the answer gets marked, although once that information is added, an actual answer becomes more appropriate.

If either of those things is more work than you'd like, believe me, I understand!  You can improve things just to the level of work that you're willing to do; SE is not paying you (in fact, they're getting paid *because* of you.)  If an answer doesn't get marked for a question, nothing terrible is going to happen.