# Set comment as answer

Tags: discussion

[image]

In this picture Robin Betts has the answer of my question, but how do I set this as **the** answer. I don't see any controls to upvote or the check-mark, the only thing I can do is add a comment..

Comment: He cannot, normally it could be up to him to change his comment into answer and you could apply it as answer, however, your question was flagged as duplicate and in that case there is no way to add new answer to your question unless it is opened again by someone higher(with higher reputation)

Comment: @MikoCG But it is always the case with every post I make, even with this one your comment is displayed as shown in the picture without the ability to up-vote (which I can't do yet) or set as answer.. The only way how to close a question for me now is to click on Answer Your Question, copy the comment of the answer and now I see the check-mark button. Maybe that is just the case?

Comment: First of all, no you cannot set a comment as answer - because it is not supposed to be taken as answer. And you cannot upvote it yet, but as soon as you have enough reputation you can do that.

Comment: If the comment solves your question and you want closure after some time, you can post it as an answer to your own question and accept it. Probably a duplicate of https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2804/mark-comment-as-answer